# Fixing ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, qgis-2, ubuntu

I have problem with installing qgis 2.0 on ubuntu 12.04.
If I don't install qgis-python plugin then qgis starts normally but I can't access python console in plugins.
If I install that plugin  then I can't even start qgis because it gives me error
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT

How I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, I think it has something to do with the procedure given for adding updated dependencies.

I can't remember *exactly* what I did to fix the problem, but it was something like this:

Using Synaptic, remove the ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable repository.

Using Synaptic, delete python-qgis and python-qgis-common

Run sudo apt-get update

Run sudo apt-get install python-qgis python-qgis-common

The object of these steps was to try to undo the changes made by following the add updated dependencies procedure.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the http://qgis.org/debian lines from your sources.list.

To do this you should open a terminal (ctrl+alt+T) and type:

sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

It'll prompt for your sudo password, then look for a line like:

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian raring main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian raring main
```

And delete both lines, or replace them by:

```
#deb http://qgis.org/debian raring main
#deb-src http://qgis.org/debian raring main
```

(adding a # at the start to make the system ignore them).

Then you should do:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```